# Substituir caractere de uma string

Tags: php

Estou tentando remover todos os hifens da minha *string* quando ela é retornada.

```
$hash = $result[2];
```

Me retorna:

```
0DE8072B-C3BE-4A94-B412-3679F7C79913
```

Quero definir uma variável que remova todos os hifens da variável `$hash`

Comment: Leia sobre [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `str_replace` nesse caso, substituindo o hífen por uma string vazia, assim:

```
$hash = str_replace("-", "", $result[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a função [str_replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

```
$new_var = str_replace("-", "alguma coisa", $hash);
```